# DataTable in .NET 4.0 Update with LINQ?

Tags: linq, datatable, dataset

I have a DataTable that looks like the below. I was wondering if anyone knew of a cool way using Linq to truncate row values based on a DataTable of string-length rules.

Table of data:

```
        var testtable = new DataTable();
        testtable.Columns.Add( "cola" , typeof( String ) );
        testtable.Columns.Add( "colb" , typeof( String ) );
        testtable.Columns.Add( "colc" , typeof( String ) );
        testtable.Rows.Add( new object[] { "1" , "22" , "333" } );
        testtable.Rows.Add( new object[] { "4444" , "55555" , "666666" } );
        testtable.Rows.Add( new object[] { "7777777" , "88888888" , "999999999" } );
```

Table of rules:

```
        var ruletable = new DataTable();
        ruletable.Columns.Add( "columnname" , typeof( String ) );
        ruletable.Columns.Add( "length" , typeof( Int32 ) );
        ruletable.Rows.Add( new object[] { "colb" , 3 } );
        ruletable.Rows.Add( new object[] { "colc" , 4 } );
```

Real life table of data has 180 columns and 1,000 rows. Table of rules has 180 rows (one per column), so I am hoping a guru can comment on how I can do something dynamic with Linq to take the leftmost characters from testtable based on what is in ruletable.

Thanks.

Comment: I am playing around with DataTable.AsEnumerable and SetField but so far am not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be as fancy as what you're looking for (and it's not using Linq) but it's straightforward and works.  I wrote it in VB cause I'm a bit quicker with that but if you need me to edit my answer with C# I can in a few minutes.

```
'loop through all of the rows in testtable'
For Each tr As Data.DataRow In testtable.Rows
    tr.BeginEdit()

    'loop through all of the rules'
    For Each drrule As Data.DataRow In ruletable.Rows
        'update the value in testtable column represented by rule rows "columnname" field'
        'based on the rules rows "length" field'
        tr(drrule("columnname")) = Left(tr(drrule("columnname")), drrule("length"))
    Next
    tr.AcceptChanges()
Next
```

Let me know if you need me to rewrite it in C# and I'll edit it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ isn't much help here - it is generally for querying data, not changing it. Since you want to update the state of each row, you are better off using an imperative approach. A nested `foreach` is probably most appropriate. You should iterate the rules first to avoid parsing the length for every row in `testTable`:

```
foreach(var ruleRow in ruleTable.AsEnumerable())
{
    var columnName = ruleRow.Field<string>("columnname");
    var length = ruleRow.Field<int>("length");

    foreach(var testRow in testTable.AsEnumerable())
    {
        var value = testRow.Field<string>(columnName);

        testRow.SetField(columnName, value.Substring(0, length));
    }
}
```

LINQ could at most be used to query for the truncated values, but you would still have to do a `foreach` to perform the update. The most LINQ can really do for you here is the `.AsEnumerable()` method on `DataTable`.